# Postgresql query (on a fixed value of a column of a table)

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I am a beginner in postgresql and I would like to ask a question.

I have a table (`mytable`) which has three columns (Customer ID(text), time(varchar), Consumption(integer))

one row, for example, is:

```
customer_id  time    consumption
C11          monday  290
```

I want to find the average consumption on sunday (only on this specified day).

I tried

```
SELECT AVG(Consumption)
FROM mytable
WHERE time='sunday';
```

but it doesn't work. I think the problem exists in the WHERE statement.

Comment: What exactly does "*it doesn't work*" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, what is the **exact** error? Do you get wrong results? If yes what do you get and what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like operator

EX:
select ...

where
time like '%sunday'

but check if exists some empty space or something like this

Comment: oh, you changed ^^

Comment: By writing                                                                                                          SELECT AVG(Consumption) FROM mytable WHERE time='sunday';

Comment: I get just a label of the avg - not its numeric value.

Comment: oooohhhhh, ok ok, change to count, sum, max, just for test. The problems stil?

Comment: in your table, have some row with time = 'sunday'?

Comment: Still the same, the output is just an empty cell.. However, I noticed that such commands work fine if the time column is not involved: eg, SELECT AVG(Consumption) 
FROM mytable
WHERE customerID='C11';                                                               so I think that there is something wrong with the declaration of time values as char or varchar and not as text (as the customerID values are declared)..                                                                                                  **Yes, there are rows with monday, sunday, etc.

Comment: try just select * whith that where, because i think you table have 0 rows with that time

Comment: ou try 
select distinct time from YOUT_TABLE

exist that time? ('sunday')

Comment: By typing SELECT * FROM mytable   , I get the right table & more specificly, the right values of the time column (monday, sunday etc - btw, the time column has values of all week days. It doesn't work with none of them).      ** Btw, at first place, the time column had timestamp values & I converted them so as to have the week day (eg, monday etc) instead of 2013-07-01 01:00:00 for example.

Comment: strange...  and with like operator? like '%monday%'

Comment: WHERE time LIKE '%sunday%';                       worked !! Thanks :-)